# Values getting rounded up in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

So basically if I try to insert a value like 2.22 it will get inserted as 2.00 instead of 2.22. I really have no idea why is this happening. I tried changing type of column in mysql but that didn't help at all.

Column in mysql is set to `Decimal(7,2)`.

Here is how i insert the value to database:

```
$ks = new ks();
$value = $_POST['value']; //value from input field
$data = $ks->getPrepare("INSERT into enties (amount) VALUES (?)");
$data->bind_param("i", $value);
$data->execute();
```

Comment: Show the code  because we have to reproduce your behavior http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ec6d/1/0

Comment: Please post how you are inserting the value from php.

Comment: `$value = $_POST['value'];` and what do you see? or better try `$value = (float) $_POST['value'];`

Comment: It displays proper value before its added to database, i just did echo $value and it showed proper value - 2.25, without using float

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, if you are trying to add decimal numbers to database with prepared statement, you have to use "d" (for double) instead of "i" in bind_param() function.

Example:

```
$value = "2.22";
$data->bind_param("i", $value);
```

Value added to database in this case will be 2.00

Example #2

```
$value = "2.22";
$data->bind_param("d", $value);
```

Value added to database in this case will be 2.22

Comment: I swear I was just going to post this, nevertheless upvoted! cheers `;-)`

Comment: Heh thanks man, I'm just glad I'm done with this issue, it was really bugging me :)